# KDE Plasma 5 - where do I check the patterns for the "in an application based on the contents of the URL" setting?

Tags: kde, browser, plasma, plasma5, kde5

In KDE Plasma 5 (e.g. install Kubuntu 20.04.2):

1. Open "System Settings";
2. Go "Applications" -> "Default Applications" -> "Web Browser";
3. There is an "Open http and https URL" setting; one of the possible values is "in an application based on the contents of the URL".

I assume it's supposed to open different applications based on patterns in the URL, e.g. if I have the Zoom app installed, Zoom meeting invitation URLs might automatically open the Zoom app instead of the default web browser.

Where do I check the patterns that are registered?